# How to draw a region of a texture/bitmap in C++?

Tags: c++, bitmap, textures, hide, crop

I'm making a minimap/radar for a game (GTA IV), and I'm wondering how to hide or remove the parts/pixels of the map texture which is outside of the square map area. The function will be run every frame, so I'm looking for an efficient way to do this, preferably with some lightweight library or directX.

What I've thought of this far is "manually" checking the coordinates of each pixel, or each line of pixels in the texture and see if it's outside the radar area, but I imagine it would take quite a lot of resources for about 4 512*512 textures every frame.

How can I do this in an efficient way?
Thanks, and sorry if this has been posted a million times, but haven't found which isn't standard image editing related.

Comment: Could you use a stencil buffer for it?

Comment: Why not to use multiplicative blending in a pixel shader with enabled transparency?

Comment: @Joe, stencil buffers seem promising! Will have to look into it.
RomanChehowsky, that could also be an option, although it seems more difficult than the stencil buffers, so I'll try those first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you want to remove pixels from the map based on the current location and the actual map. Why simply not use transparency? Basically, you fill the pixel data on the CPU (in your game code) and then update the texture on the video card. Even better if the map doesn't change, you can do all that in a big texture first and load it on the GPU (or even do it manually) and change the texture coordinates to display the portion that interest you.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm probably going to do. The problem here is the parts of the textures which overflow the defined area. How would you make those parts transparent? Multiplicative blending, like commented in the question, could be a nice and effective solution.